# "Including" XAML page in my main XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a TabItem with a DataGrid and a Graph next to it, this TabItem basically has to be copied on 26 different TabItems, but each with a different DataSource. I was wondering if there is a way to put this page with the DataGrid and the Graph on a seperate XAML page and then reference it on each different TabItem.

Should this be possible, is it also possible to pass on variables to this XAML page as each DataGrid would have a different DataBinding source.

Code of the page:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.65*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.35*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" TabStripPlacement="Bottom">
        <TabItem Header="OPPERVLAKKEN" Controls:ControlsHelper.HeaderFontSize="14">
            <GroupBox Header="waterbalans grafiek" 
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Canvas x:Name="OppervlakkenCanvas" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" SizeChanged="GrafiekTekenen"/>
            </GroupBox>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="VOORZIENINGEN" Controls:ControlsHelper.HeaderFontSize="14">
            <GroupBox Header="waterbalans grafiek"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Canvas x:Name="VoorzieningenCanvas" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" SizeChanged="GrafiekTekenen"/>
            </GroupBox>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
    <TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="0" TabStripPlacement="Bottom">
        <TabItem Header="RESULTAAT" Controls:ControlsHelper.HeaderFontSize="14">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <GroupBox Header="waterbalans afvoerend oppervlak" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Input.ResultatenCollectie[0].Oppervlakken}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Style="{DynamicResource ResultatenTabel}"
                              CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False"
                              FrozenColumnCount="2" Margin="0,0,0,0" IsReadOnly="True" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="25" Header="#" Binding="{Binding Path=Resultaten[0].Int}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource OmschrijvingHeader}" CellStyle="{StaticResource OmschrijvingCell}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="oppervlak" Binding="{Binding Path=Resultaten[1].String}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource OmschrijvingHeader}" CellStyle="{StaticResource OmschrijvingCell}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="100" Header="neerslag&#x0a;          (m³)" Binding="{Binding Path=Resultaten[2].Double, StringFormat={}{0:f2}}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="100" Header="verdampt&#x0a;           (m&#xb3;)" Binding="{Binding Path=Resultaten[3].Double, StringFormat={}{0:f2}}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource VerdamptHeader}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="125" Header="geinfiltreerd&#x0a;                  (m&#xb3;)" Binding="{Binding Path=Resultaten[4].Double, StringFormat={}{0:f2}}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource GeinfiltreerdHeader}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="100" Header="geborgen&#x0a;           (m&#xb3;)" Binding="{Binding Path=Resultaten[5].Double, StringFormat={}{0:f2}}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource GeborgenHeader}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="125" Header="afgestroomd&#x0a;                   (m&#xb3;)" Binding="{Binding Path=Resultaten[6].Double, StringFormat={}{0:f2}}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource AfgestroomdHeader}"/>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
                </GroupBox>
                <GroupBox Header="waterbalans voorziening" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" 
                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Input.ResultatenCollectie[0].Voorziening}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Style="{DynamicResource ResultatenTabel}"
                              CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False"
                              FrozenColumnCount="2" Margin="0,0,0,0" IsReadOnly="True" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="25" Header="#" Binding="{Binding Path=Resultaten[0].Int}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource OmschrijvingHeader}" CellStyle="{StaticResource OmschrijvingCell}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="element" Binding="{Binding Path=Resultaten[1].String}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource OmschrijvingHeader}" CellStyle="{StaticResource OmschrijvingCell}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="100" Header="inloop&#x0a;      (m&#xb3;)" Binding="{Binding Path=Resultaten[2].Double, StringFormat={}{0:f2}}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="100" Header="geborgen&#x0a;           (m&#xb3;)" Binding="{Binding Path=Resultaten[3].Double, StringFormat={}{0:f2}}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource GeborgenHeader}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="100" Header="geledigd&#x0a;         (m&#xb3;)" Binding="{Binding Path=Resultaten[4].Double, StringFormat={}{0:f2}}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource GeinfiltreerdHeader}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="125" Header="overgelopen&#x0a;                 (m&#xb3;)" Binding="{Binding Path=Resultaten[5].Double, StringFormat={}{0:f2}}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource AfgestroomdHeader}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="125" Header="overloop&#x0a;frequentie" Binding="{Binding Path=Resultaten[6].Double, StringFormat={}{0:f0}}"/>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
                </GroupBox>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="GEGEVENS" Controls:ControlsHelper.HeaderFontSize="14">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <GroupBox Header="gegevens afvoerend oppervlak" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Input.OppervlakGegevens}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Style="{DynamicResource ResultatenTabel}"
                              CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False"
                              FrozenColumnCount="1" Margin="0,0,0,0" IsReadOnly="True">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="omschrijving" Binding="{Binding Path=Gegevens[0].String}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource OmschrijvingHeader}" CellStyle="{StaticResource OmschrijvingCell}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="grootte&#x0a;oppervlak (m&#xb2;)" Binding="{Binding Path=Gegevens[1].Double, StringFormat={}{0:f2}}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="1.1*" Header="afstromings&#x0a;vertraging (min&#x207b;&#xb9;)" Binding="{Binding Path=Gegevens[2].Double, StringFormat={}{0:f2}}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="oppervlakte&#x0a;berging (mm)" Binding="{Binding Path=Gegevens[3].Double, StringFormat={}{0:f2}}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="verdampings&#x0a;factor (0-1)" Binding="{Binding Path=Gegevens[4].Double, StringFormat={}{0:f2}}"/>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
                </GroupBox>
                <GroupBox Header="gegevens voorziening" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" 
                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Input.VoorzieningGegevens}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Style="{DynamicResource ResultatenTabel}"
                              CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False"
                              FrozenColumnCount="1" Margin="0,0,0,0" IsReadOnly="True">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="element" Binding="{Binding Path=Gegevens[0].String}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource OmschrijvingHeader}" CellStyle="{StaticResource OmschrijvingCell}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="berging&#x0a;(mm)" Binding="{Binding Path=Gegevens[1].Double, StringFormat={}{0:f2}}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="ledigings&#x0a;capaciteit (mm/h)" Binding="{Binding Path=Gegevens[2].Double, StringFormat={}{0:f2}}"/>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
                </GroupBox>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

The only thing that would have to be different on each page is:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Input.ResultatenCollectie[0].Oppervlakken}"
```

The 0 would have to be a 1, then a 2, etc

Answer (score 0):

> I think the best solution would be to use a ItemsControl with a
>   DataTemplate. In this DataTemplate you define to use "your" Control.
>   The problem with the DataSource is, that you need the possibility to
>   define it on each control. Where do you try to get these DataSources?
>   Best solution would be to add a Dependendy Property in "your" Control
>   and bind it in the DataTemplate. But please: show us some code!

Edit:
I completely misunderstood your problem. Here is another advice:
Create a new WPF UserControl (MyTabItem.xaml)

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.MyTabItem"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <TabItem Header="RESULTAAT">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <GroupBox Header="waterbalans afvoerend oppervlak" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <DataGrid x:Name="MyDataGrid"  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Style="{DynamicResource ResultatenTabel}"
                          CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False"
                          FrozenColumnCount="2" Margin="0,0,0,0" IsReadOnly="True" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Width="25" Header="#" Binding="{Binding Path=Resultaten[0].Int}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource OmschrijvingHeader}" CellStyle="{StaticResource OmschrijvingCell}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="oppervlak" Binding="{Binding Path=Resultaten[1].String}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource OmschrijvingHeader}" CellStyle="{StaticResource OmschrijvingCell}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Width="100" Header="neerslag&#x0a;          (m³)" Binding="{Binding Path=Resultaten[2].Double, StringFormat={}{0:f2}}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Width="100" Header="verdampt&#x0a;           (m&#xb3;)" Binding="{Binding Path=Resultaten[3].Double, StringFormat={}{0:f2}}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource VerdamptHeader}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Width="125" Header="geinfiltreerd&#x0a;                  (m&#xb3;)" Binding="{Binding Path=Resultaten[4].Double, StringFormat={}{0:f2}}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource GeinfiltreerdHeader}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Width="100" Header="geborgen&#x0a;           (m&#xb3;)" Binding="{Binding Path=Resultaten[5].Double, StringFormat={}{0:f2}}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource GeborgenHeader}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Width="125" Header="afgestroomd&#x0a;                   (m&#xb3;)" Binding="{Binding Path=Resultaten[6].Double, StringFormat={}{0:f2}}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource AfgestroomdHeader}"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </GroupBox>
            <GroupBox Header="waterbalans voorziening" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" 
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Input.ResultatenCollectie[0].Voorziening}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Style="{DynamicResource ResultatenTabel}"
                          CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False"
                          FrozenColumnCount="2" Margin="0,0,0,0" IsReadOnly="True" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Width="25" Header="#" Binding="{Binding Path=Resultaten[0].Int}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource OmschrijvingHeader}" CellStyle="{StaticResource OmschrijvingCell}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="element" Binding="{Binding Path=Resultaten[1].String}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource OmschrijvingHeader}" CellStyle="{StaticResource OmschrijvingCell}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Width="100" Header="inloop&#x0a;      (m&#xb3;)" Binding="{Binding Path=Resultaten[2].Double, StringFormat={}{0:f2}}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Width="100" Header="geborgen&#x0a;           (m&#xb3;)" Binding="{Binding Path=Resultaten[3].Double, StringFormat={}{0:f2}}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource GeborgenHeader}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Width="100" Header="geledigd&#x0a;         (m&#xb3;)" Binding="{Binding Path=Resultaten[4].Double, StringFormat={}{0:f2}}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource GeinfiltreerdHeader}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Width="125" Header="overgelopen&#x0a;                 (m&#xb3;)" Binding="{Binding Path=Resultaten[5].Double, StringFormat={}{0:f2}}" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource AfgestroomdHeader}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Width="125" Header="overloop&#x0a;frequentie" Binding="{Binding Path=Resultaten[6].Double, StringFormat={}{0:f0}}"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </GroupBox>
        </Grid>
    </TabItem>
</Grid>
```

With MyTabItem.xaml.cs

```
    /// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MyTabItem.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MyTabItem : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyDatasourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyDatasource", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(MyTabItem), new PropertyMetadata(default(IEnumerable), MyDataSourceChangedCallback));

    private static void MyDataSourceChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var myobj = d as MyTabItem;
        if (myobj == null) return;
        myobj.MyDataSourceChanged(d, e);
    }

    private void MyDataSourceChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    {
        MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs.NewValue as IEnumerable;
    }

    public MyTabItem()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public IEnumerable MyDatasource
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(MyDatasourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyDatasourceProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
        <TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="0" TabStripPlacement="Bottom">
        <wpfApplication1:MyTabItem MyDatasource="{Binding Path=Input.ResultatenCollectie[0].Oppervlakken}"       />
        <wpfApplication1:MyTabItem MyDatasource="{Binding Path=Input.ResultatenCollectie[1].Oppervlakken}"       />
        <wpfApplication1:MyTabItem MyDatasource="{Binding Path=Input.ResultatenCollectie[2].Oppervlakken}"       />
    </TabControl>
```

Comment: Pretty much what I was looking for, and I already found some UserControl instructions also while searching. The main error I am getting now is that all the HeaderStyle's can't be resolved etc and the SizeChanged="GrafiekTekenen" is throwing an error too

Comment: I fixed the styles by simply copying the Resources to the UserControl, but what about my GrafiekTekenen event?

Comment: What about this event? It is in the TabControl above the TabControl I was touching...

Comment: Ahh I see, I need that TabControl to also be part of the UserControl